# How can I handle offline logout with Firebase in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm unsure how to handle logout in my IOS app when the user is offline.

I'm using Firebase in Swift for authentication and it works perfectly when online for login/logout. However, I want to let the user logout when offline. Currently, when offline and the user clicks the Logout button, nothing happens on screen. If I restart the app, I am taken to the login screen as-if the logout occurred.

```
do {
   try Auth.auth().signOut()
} catch let signOutError as NSError {
   print (signOutError)
}
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMain", sender: self)
```

This code works for signout when online, but when offline the segue is not performed. I've also tried putting segue in the do and catch.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to work for me, so let's dig a little deeper here. can you put some breakpoints in the try/catch block so you can see what code is being reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
  if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Welcome")
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked. The login VC was presented when I was offline and clicked logout.

I was trying to use an unwind segue back to the login VC so that the VC's previously on-screen would no longer be in memory or in the stack. Does instantiating and presenting the vc as above remove the previous VC's from memory?